# Am-time-ago with timezone

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I am trying to display the time ago in an angular.js app with angular-moment, moment, and moment-timezone.  I got everything to work however the time is 6 hours off for someone in Spain.  Which is 6 hour time difference from where I live.  I want the time ago to be uniformed for every person in the world.  When I change the timezone it doesn't seem to do anything and I couldn't find any documentation on how to add the timezones.  Unfortunately all of the times in the database are configured to the servers timezone.  Here's my attempt

view.html:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="d in data">
            <td><span am-time-ago="d.date"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

app.js:

```
var arcs = angular.module('arcs', ['ui.router', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMdIcons', 'angularMoment']);

$.getJSON('bower_components/moment-timezone/data/packed/latest.json', function(data) {
    moment.tz.add(data['zones']);
    arcs.constant('angularMomentConfig', {timezone: 'Europe/Amsterdam'});
});
```

index.html:

```
...
  <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/moment-timezone/moment-timezone-utils.js"></script>
...
```

Comment: What does a date from the database look like? Does it have a timezone? Format could be YYYY-MM-DDTHH:ii:ssZZZ where ZZZ is the timezone offset (+0600). If your dates don't contain this information then moment won't know it needs to convert them to local timezone.

Comment: It looks like this "2015-09-21 15:36:15" so "YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss".  The problem is I think I would have to change a lot of code if I where to add a timezone/swtich to epoch time.  There is another cakephp application that uses the same database and in that app the date is auto-generated on model creation.

Comment: Well, if you are sure all of them are server time, and you know server timezone, then you can simply add the timezone offset before passing them to moment.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store epoch time in your database? That way moment will adjust all times for the right time zone. Use `moment().valueOf()` to make a timestamp of the event. In the directive, you can use something like this: `$(elm[0]).html(moment(epochTime).fromNow());`